# Hide perspective in eclipse with xml

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I'm new to this whole eclipse RCP and PDE thing, so any help most welcome !

Basically I've created a new perspective, mostly using xml perspective and perspectiveExtension in my plugin.xml. It generally works fine, but I need it to only be activated in our productized application and "turn it off" when we export as plugins...

Is this possible via xml ? Or are there other ways of doing this ?

I've tried using activity/activityPatternBindings, but this doesn't seem to work, i.e.:

```
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
   <activity id="com.x.y.z.disable"
           name="HidePerspective">
      <enabledWhen>
         <with variable="true">
            <equals value="false">
            </equals>
         </with>
      </enabledWhen>
   </activity>
   <activityPatternBinding activityId="com.x.y.z.disable"
                          pattern="com.x.y.z.MyPerspective">
   </activityPatternBinding>
   </extension>
```

If the above worked OK - switching on/off the perspective by changing value="false" to value="true", then I was going to substitute in a property tester for org.eclipse.core.runtime.product. Anyone know if this is a valid approach or why the above doesn't work ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In the end I created a new feature that was only available with the productized application - so pretty much avoided the issue above...

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined your perspective in plugin.xml, then try to just remove it in Java code, when it is not needed (see this blog post how to do it http://commercialjavaproducts.blogspot.com/2011/07/remove-unwanted-perspectives-from-your.html).

Also, you may want to take a look at Eclipse Fragments, which, I think could solve your problem in more elegant way.

Or try to create such plugins hierarchy, where you don't depend on the plugin with perspective and can export only those plugins, you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern in the binding is wrong. There are two ways to use these patterns: Either with the intention to match multiple IDs, then there should be some wildcard characters. Or to match exactly one ID, then it needs to be of the form "plugin.id/perspective.id" and the attribute "isEqualityPattern" should be set to true.

Have a look at the example code in http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/

Another important point: While activity bindings can hide UI elements, those UI elements will *automatically* be shown again, if the workbench needs them. So if your workspace contains a Java project, Eclipse *will* show the Java UI elements, even if they were hidden via pattern binding before. Therefore you might want to experiment with cleaning your workspace when trying your bindings (as the workspace might be in a state where your binding is already ignored).